# Hi, I am trying to parse google results page to extract all the URL's

Tags: php, parsing, dom, google-search

I have tried the following code to get a list of all URL's from google search results. But I am able to find the URL with the description. I want to get only the URL's as a list.

```
<?php
include('simple_html_dom.php');
function file_get_contents_curl($url)
{
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); //Set curl to return the data instead of printing it to the browser.
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  $data = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  return $data;
}
$query      = "what is a car";
$url        = 'http://www.google.com/search?q=' . urlencode($query) . '';
$scrape     = file_get_contents_curl($url);
//gettype($scrape); 
//echo $scrape;
$domResults = new simple_html_dom();
$domResults->load($scrape);
foreach ($domResults->find('a[href^=/url?q]') as $element) {
  echo $element . '<br><br>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the last loop with:

```
$result = "";
foreach($domResults->find('a[href^=/url?q]') as $element) {
    $result .=  $element->href."\n";
    //echo $element.'<br><br>';
}
file_put_contents("myresult.txt", $result, FILE_APPEND);
```

but you can do the same only with this :) (with addition of your 2 last "demand")

```
<?php
include ('simple_html_dom.php');
$query = "what is a car";
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/search?q='.urlencode($query));
$result = "";
foreach($html->find('a[href^=/url?q]') as $element) {
   $url = $element->href;
   $url = str_replace("/url?q=","",$url);
   $result .=  $url."\n";
   echo "<a href='".$url."'>".$url."</a><br>";

}
file_put_contents("myresult.txt", $result, FILE_APPEND);
?>
```

Comment: Well that helped a bit. But i want to get the results as a list which i can store as a text file.

Comment: Also the results I get are links which cannot be opened.Can u please help me

Comment: I edited my response for saving to a file (remove the FILE_APPEND option to overwrite the file at each update.

On the other hand in a message you want to save in a file and in a 2nd to be able to click on it ... you have to decide;)

to restore the clickable link you have to delete the beginning "/ url? q =" then use the url via <a> tags

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function file_put_content() in C:\xampp\htdocs\tutorial youtube\website links.php:10 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\tutorial youtube\website links.php on line 10

Comment: yes typing error ... corrected + addition of clickable links

Comment: Also can u say me a way to remove the extensions of the result....
currently i get the results as 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Car&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwjtlK6vpJXrAhX88XMBHdEEC0YQmhMwDHoECBMQDg&usg=AOvVaw2UctL1mKzCFJGRqEVF537h
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Car&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwjtlK6vpJXrAhX88XMBHdEEC0YQFjAaegQIAxAB&usg=AOvVaw0UwW9Gm5X1RhHKj_z9RPup
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_car&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwjtlK6vpJXrAhX88XMBHdEEC0YQ0gIwGnoECAMQAg&usg=AOvVaw0sAhabdslmBeLwmB9UAKh_

so how do i remove the characters after '/wiki/car' in the first result ... and like wise all the results..

Comment: This will be my last answer, because you keep asking new questions, without even having validated my answer linked to your initial question, you are not playing the game.

=> list ($url, $tmp) = explode ("&", $url, 2);